# matplotlib subplots don't honor ylim

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create 9 subplots (3x3) ***all with the same x and y ranges***. I setup the plots using this code, and all but the last subplot use the correct y-range (ylim).

```
brightM = -22 # Plot range... 
limitM  = -14
dataIn = np.load("testLFdata.tst.npy",allow_pickle=True)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex='all',sharey='all',figsize=(15,15))
linaxs   = axs.reshape(-1)
for i, ax in zip(range(dataIn[0].size), linaxs):
    print("z={}".format(dataIn[0,i]))
    xdata = dataIn[1,i][0]
    ydata = dataIn[1,i][1]
    ax.plot(xdata,ydata,ls='-',marker='o', c="b")

    # Format plt
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.set_ylim([5e-6,1e-1])
    ax.set_yticks(np.logspace(-6,-1,6))
    ax.set_xscale('linear')
    ax.set_xlim([brightM-0.85,limitM+0.5])
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(brightM,limitM+1,2))
    ax.set_xticklabels([str(i) for i in np.arange(brightM,limitM+1,2)])
    ax.grid(b=True)
    gc.collect()
    
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, bottom=0.08, right=1.0, top=1.0, wspace=.0, hspace=.0)
gc.collect()
```

[Here's the data for the data struct "dataIn"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t716a8foddqk7tl/testLFdata.tst.npy?dl=0).

Here's the plot I get... As you can see the lower-right plot has the wrong y-limits!

[image: 9x subplots]

Comment: `set_yticks` will change the ylims.  Swap the order of `ax.set_yticks(np.logspace(-6,-1,6)), ax.set_ylim([5e-6,1e-1])` and it should be fine

Comment: @JodyKlymak -- thx! I'll try that as soon as I get home.